# Бот для сообщества ВК на Python

Tags: python, вконтакте

Помогите с написанием кода для Бота в ВК

```
import vk_api
import random
import time
token = "ТУТ ТОКЕН"


vk = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)

vk._auth_token()

while True:

try:
    print('Бот запущен')
    messages = vk.method("messages.getConversations", {"offset": 0, "count": 20, "filter": "unanswered"})
    if messages["count"] >= 1:
        id = messages["items"][0]["last_message"]["from_id"]
        body = messages["items"][0]["last_message"]["text"]
        if body.lower() == "привет":
            vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "Привет!", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
        elif body.lower() == "кто я?":
            vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "Ты хороший человек", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
        elif body.lower() == "!тест":
            vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "Бот работает!", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
        elif body.lower() == "!команды":
            vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "Список команд\n!тест\n привет\n кто я?", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
        else:
            vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "я не знаю что значит " + str(body.lower()), "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
except Exception as E:
    time.sleep(1)
```

Нужно добавить вариацию команд, например не только с маленькой буквы, но и с большой. Как отправлять картинки и тд. Хостинг бота.

Comment: Документация... Хостинг, купить сервер, как вариант

Comment: *не только с маленькой буквы, но и с большой* - приводите к одному регистру. *Как отправлять картинки* - смотрите документацию. *Хостинг бота* - ищите хостинг.